# C# Сортировка listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

Заношу в Listbox все имена найденных файлов в папке. Включен параметр Sorted. Сортирует только по первому символу. Нужно чтобы сортировало и десятичные числа[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(findFolder);
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*jpg");
            foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(fi.ToString());
                termsList.Add(fi.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Обычная строковая сортировка - по кодам символов, тут отсортировано по всем символам, не только по первым, как вы думаете. Хотите "числовую" сортировку - можете дополнить слева нулями, чтобы было одинаковое число позиций в каждом названии. Тогда "02-..." и "17-..." отсортируется "правильно".

Comment: @CrazyElf Мне очень важно чтобы было без нуля было. Как то можно эту проблему исправить?

Comment: Пробелы тоже можно попробовать вместо нулей. Ну либо нужно сразу добавлять в порядке нужной сортировки элементы и без Sorted тогда.

Comment: Вы можете унаследовать класс ListBox и переопределить в нём метод Sort() так, как вы этого хотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать как советуют тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012647/custom-listbox-sorting. Наследуетесь от ListBox и переопределяете метод сортировки. Там можете из строк выкидывать всё что не цифры.
Вот ещё пример из документации: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListBox_Sort